# Jquery Thumbnail image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added the JQuery Lightbox to my ASP.net application. But I have a problem when i click on thumbnail  image the preview image shown is very big image with scroll up-down, right-left. Like this iamge

[image]

and I want to display the image preview like this.

[image]

How i can fix the width and height for specific preview? Which file should I edit or change for this purpose?. The file added are image is given below.

[image]

The ASP.net code is given Below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyAPNSWebApp._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Jquery LightBox Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox_resize.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox_r.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#gallery a').lightBox();
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        /* jQuery lightBox plugin - Gallery style */
            #gallery {
                background-color: #444;
                padding: 2px;
                width: 800px;
            }
            #gallery ul { list-style: none; }
            #gallery ul li { display: inline; }
            #gallery ul img {
                border: 5px solid #3e3e3e;
                border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
            }
            #gallery ul a:hover img {
                border: 5px solid #fff;
                border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
                color: #fff;
            }
            #gallery ul a:hover { color: #fff; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">       
            <h2 id="example">Example</h2>
            <p>Click in the image and see the <strong>jQuery lightBox plugin</strong> in action.</p>
            <div id="gallery">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="photos/image1.jpg" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                            <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="photos/image2.jpg" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                            <img src="photos/thumb_image2.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="photos/image3.jpg" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                            <img src="photos/thumb_image3.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="photos/image4.jpg" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                            <img src="photos/thumb_image4.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="photos/image5.jpg" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                            <img src="photos/thumb_image5.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any one know about my problem??

Comment: There are other Lightbox style plugins that make the image fit in your viewport when you click to open the big image, or do that same thing and in addition to that, also resizes the image on window resize. http://fancybox.net/ -- http://www.shadowbox-js.com/download.html ( Of the top of my head I can't remember any other ones that do these things )

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
    });
</script>
```

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#gallery a').lightBox({
       maxHeight: 500,
       maxWidth: 700
    });
</script>
```

replace values with your own choice.

Comment: This open the image in new page (url=http://localhost:1608/photos/image5.jpg), but i want to preview like lightbox popup as above 2nd image of red leaves.

Comment: In you every anchor tag add rel="lightbox" and then check.

Comment: I think the lightBox is previewing actual size if images. I need to fix the height and width of images as my all images are of same properties.

Comment: I am not sure but it could be a JQuery conflict problem.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem of image height / width.

Comment: May b, Its my first usage of Jquery, perhaps i did any mistake, but i am un aware :(